# Might any damage have been caused when cancelling the update manager in Linux Mint during an update?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, authentication

My Linux Mint Update Manager was running an update - a very big one. It was in the middle of downloading package files, and it was taking way too long and I had to stop it, so I clicked Cancel. When I resumed it later, it presented me with a screen I had never seen before. It showed me a list of all packages to be installed, sorted by `Not Authenticated` and two other categories, likely `Authenticated` and the one in between. There were 23 packages in `Not Authenticated` if I remember correctly (I do not have any screenshot saved of the screen I saw). I clicked Apply, as I did not know what else to do, but it warned me that all the packages in `Not Authenticated` could be malicious software. So what happened? Why did I get this screen after cancelling the update in the middle of the download and then trying to resume it? Might any damage have been done?